# Android AlarmManager & Notification

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I need the `AlarmManager` to push a notification at the same time everyday. When I first loaded the app, it worked as I expected. Unfortunately after I rebooted my phone, there's no notification at the time. If I open the app, the notification does show. What I need is to remind the user to use the app when they don't. If they have to enter the app for it to work, it's worthless.

Here is some of my code:

```
AlarmManager am = getAlarmManager(ctx);
Intent i = new Intent(ctx, UpdateReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, i, 0);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
//If current time is later than 22, the alarm time should set 22 in the next day
if (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)>22)
{
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1);
}
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP ,cal.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

How can I get the app to always send the notifications correctly?

Comment: Same problem i was facing but after i used .BootCompletedReceiver and database to store that details of times i am done with it :)

Comment: I moved the app to AVD, and it could work. My test phone is not original Android OS, I guess the ROM has changed the way AlarmManager works. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately when you restart the device all of the `AlarmManager` stuff will be cleared.

> ...will be cleared if it is turned off and rebooted.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

You have to register a `BroadcastReceiver` for the boot like this:

```
<receiver android:name="com.your.app.BootCompletedReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

From your receiver you have to schedule your notification again (just like you do in your post).

Comment: Acctually, I do have BroadcastReceiver after boot just like you said, the code:

Comment: `public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
        {
                Toast.makeText(context,"set Alarm when boot",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                AlarmManagerUtil.sendUpdateBroadcast(context);
        }
    }`      I can see the toast text , but still no notification.

Comment: What does the `AlarmManagerUtil.sendUpdateBroadcast(context);` do?

Comment: It's the code I post in the question.           ` public static void sendUpdateBroadcast(Context ctx)
    {
        AlarmManager am = getAlarmManager(ctx);
        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, UpdateReceiver.class);  `

Comment: Interesting... It should work like that. What android version do you use?

Comment: I moved the app to AVD, and it could work. My test phone is not original Android OS, I guess the ROM has changed the way AlarmManager works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, I think my code is right. so I moved the app to AVD, and it could work. My test phone is not original Android OS, I guess the ROM has changed the way AlarmManager works.